# Creating a dynamic button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to creat a dynamic button in a my application. So basically I have this code but when I run it I don’t see the bottom in the other form . The panel is empty. I  create the bottom on a button click in a first form then it has to show the button in the second form’s panel.

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form wrr = new Interface();
    wrr.Show();
    createnutton();
}

int i = 0;
int x = 0;

private void createnutton()
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(3 + i, 14 + x);
    btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    btn.Text = "Tabel" + libtno.Text;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    panel3.Controls.Add(btn);
    i += 10;
    x += 10;
}

void btn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("me");
}
```

Comment: You're adding a new Button to `panel3.Controls` in the current Form. Did you mean to add these new Controls to the Form initialized as `Form wrr = new Interface();`?

Comment: I am trying to add it to another form with the name Interface .

Comment: Well, then you have to call that method from the instance of the new Form. First of all, change the class name, from `Interface` to something else (the `Interface` name is already taken :). Assume the name will be `frmInterface`, then you have `var wrr = new frmInterface();`. Subscribe to the `Load` event of the Form and call `CreateButton()` (this also renamed) from the `Load` handler. You can then call `CreateButton()` from anywhere else in the Form (a `Button.Click` handler, maybe)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set one more property "Visible=true" for your Button.

Comment: That's irrelevant: new Controls are visible by default, when added to a Container. `BringToFront()` may be needed, but it appears the OP is trying to do something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the instance of Interface that you created.  Pass `wrr` to your `createnutton` function.  For this to work, you have to change the MODIFIERS property of `panel3` to PUBLIC.  You also can't reference the Form with the generic Form type.  It has to be of that specific Form type, which is `Interface` (a horrible name by the way, since `interface` has different meaning in C#):

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Interface wrr = new Interface();
    wrr.Show();
    createnutton(wrr); // <-- pass "wrr" to the function
}

int i = 0;
int x = 0;

private void createnutton(Interface frmInterface) // <-- parameter added
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(3 + i, 14 + x);
    btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    btn.Text = "Tabel" + libtno.Text;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    frmInterface.panel3.Controls.Add(btn); // <-- use the passed in form
    i += 10;
    x += 10;
}
```

BUT...this seems like a horrible design.  I wouldn't do this if I were personally writing from the ground up.

Comment: For learning purposes, if you were to do it in your own way. Ie creating a dynamic button from a click of a button on a old form to create a new button on a new form.

Comment: But why are you creating these buttons dynamically in the first place?  Why are they not being created at design time?  We'd need a lot more information about the "big picture" to help you re-design.

Comment: So I am designed a pos system. When the items are are been added and the table is not close instantly, then there is a button send with will create a dynamic button for the use to use to reopen the table to add items or close the table